# Is it possible to initialize an object as a function with properties?

Tags: javascript

Is there any possibility to initialize an object as a function with properties?
Something like this:

```js
var a = {
    () => {
        return "I am function!";
    },
    prop1: "I am property in function object",
    prop2: 10
}

alert(a()); // => I am function!
alert(a.prop1); // => I am property in function object
```

I know that I can do it like this:

```js
var a = () => "I am function!";
a.prop1 = "I am property in function object";
a.prop2 = 10;
```

I'm just wondering if this is possible.

Comment: You cannot turn a plain object into a function, but you can treat a function as an object and add arbitrary properties to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isnt. The only way to create an object with the internal `[[call]]` property, is a function literal or through class / object method declarations.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no literal syntax for functions with properties (or making objects callable). You can however use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to put everything in a single statement:

```
const a = Object.assign(() => {
    return "I am function!";
}, {
    prop1: "I am property in function object",
    prop2: 10
});

console.log(a()); // => I am function!
console.log(a.prop1); // => I am property in function object
```